# paypal recurring payments and paypal pro

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, recurring

I am trying to implement paypal pro (our software should work for an italian account) for recurring payments.
I cannot use "express checkout" beacuse a subscription can vary more than the 15% limitation in 180 days and we don't have a trial period.
I have downloaded samples from paypal for .net, created a sandbox account from the developer dashboard but when i test it, i give an error message "DPRP is disabled for this merchant".
Later i have read that recurring payments are enabled for "direct payments" but they are enabled only in US, UK, Canada and New Zealand.
In Paypal Pro for Italy documentation i have not found any information for Recurring Payments.
How can I create a recurring payment in Paypal without "express checkout" then?

Answer (score 0):

With an Italian PayPal account you're not going to be able to use Payments Pro.

What you could do, though, is use Express Checkout with [Billing Agreements](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/create-billing-agreement/) / [Reference Transactions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-refTrans-SetEC-DoRefTrans-curl-etc/?mark=reference%20transaction) instead of setting up a recurring payments profile.  This way you won't have the 15% limitation.

You would include the billing agreement parameters in your SetExpressCheckout request, and then that would setup the billing agreement so that you can run future calls to DoReferenceTransaction to process some amount in the future using the billing agreement.

This way the process happens without additional approval, no redirect required, etc.  You just make the DoReferenceTransaction call and the money is moved immediately.  Reference transactions can be any amount, so you would have no limitation there.

The only difference with this method is that you'll need to create a CRON job on your server that loops through all your due accounts each day to run the reference transaction for each one.  So you're basically building your own recurring system instead of using PayPal's.

If you happen to be working with PHP this [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) will make all of the API calls very quick and easy for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will go trought with reference transactions.
I'm developing in a c# application (asp.net) but I think that it will be not difficult find an example.
I have already implemented a job scheduler (http://hangfire.io/) that supports CRON in my project and with your answer i think it will be more suitable the transaction solution instead of a recurring payment.
From the PayPal developer reference the Billing Agreement is deprecated since version 54.0. Is it also valid?

Comment: I think they got rid of one particular call because now you just use Express Checkout to handle it.  It's still a billing agreement, though.